# how to parse http request in c++

Tags: c++, parsing, http

I'm trying to write a small c++ webserver which handles GET, POST, HEAD requests. My problem is I don't know how to parse the headers, message body, etc. It's listening on the socket, I can even write stuff out to the browser just fine, but I'm curious how should I do this in c++.

Afaik a standard GET/POST request should look something like this:

```
GET /index HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.0.199:80
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.22 (KHTML, like Gecko)     Chrome/25.0.1364.97 Safari/537.22
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3

this is the message body
```

All lines ended with '\r\n'.

Should I just split the request at '\n' and trim them (and if so how)?
Also how to handle files in post data?

Main thing I want to achieve is to get a vector containing headers key=>value pairs, a string with request method, the post data (like in PHP, if it's present), and the query string (/index for example) as string or vector splitted by '/'.

Thanks!

Comment: It's an overkill to handle web stuff with C++. But if you really want to go that far you better be ready for way harder string manipulation than this one.

Comment: If you want to parse HTTP messages, the only question you need to ask is ... *How many times must I read [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html) before it all sinks in?*

Comment: Do you want to write your own server as an exercise or do you want to **use** a web server library from within C++? In that case, there are very good solutions out there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before doing everything yourself, I introduce you [Poco](https://pocoproject.org/):

```
class MyHTTPRequestHandler : public HTTPRequestHandler
{
public:
    virtual void handleRequest(HTTPServerRequest & request,
                               HTTPServerResponse & response) {
        // Write your HTML response in res object
    }
};

class MyRequestHandlerFactory : public HTTPRequestHandlerFactory
{
    MyHTTPRequestHandler handler;

public:
    MyRequestHandlerFactory(){}
    HTTPRequestHandler* createRequestHandler(const HTTPServerRequest& request)
    {
        const string method = request.getMethod();
        if (method == "get" || method == "post")
            return &handler;
        return 0;
    }
};

int main()
{
    HTTPServerParams params;
    params.setMaxQueued(100);
    params.setMaxThreads(16);
    ServerSocket svs(80);
    MyRequestHandlerFactory factory;
    HTTPServer srv(&factory, svs, &params);
    srv.start();
    while (true)
        Thread::sleep(1000);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Boost.Asio is a good library but relativel low-level. You’ll really want to use a higher level library. [There’s a modern C++ library called **node.native**](https://github.com/d5/node.native) which you should check out. A very server can be implemented as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <native/native.h>
using namespace native::http;

int main() {
    http server;
    if(!server.listen("0.0.0.0", 8080, [](request& req, response& res) {
        res.set_status(200);
        res.set_header("Content-Type", "text/plain");
        res.end("C++ FTW\n");
    })) return 1; // Failed to run server.

    std::cout << "Server running at http://0.0.0.0:8080/" << std::endl;
    return native::run();
}
```

It doesn’t get much simpler than this.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to consider [Proxygen](https://github.com/facebook/proxygen), Facebook's C++ HTTP framework.  It's open source under a BSD license.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is basically just string parsing and then the response creating that goes back to the browser, following [the specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html).

But if this is not just an hobby project and you do not want to take on a really big task you should use either Apache, if you need a web server you need to extend, or [tntnet](http://www.tntnet.org/), if you need a c++ web framework, or [cpp-netlib](http://cpp-netlib.org/latest/index.html) if you need C++ network stuff.