# How to queue the previous http request and read another request without blocking the event loop?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, http, server

The event loop looks like this:

```
while(1)
{
    if ((new_socket = accept(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address, (socklen_t*)&addrlen))<0)
    {
        perror("In accept");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    char buffer[30000] = {0};
    valread = read( new_socket , buffer, 30000);
    printf("%s\n",buffer );
}
```

I intend to queue the previous http request. Then at latter time reply them to the client using

```
write(new_socket , hello , strlen(hello));
close(new_socket);
```

However, as soon as I read it without writing, I get blocking, so I could not get the new incoming http and queue the previous. What is the proper way of implementing http queue that has been read already?

Comment: Essentially you are asking how to keep multiple TCP connections open at the same time within your program. Either use multiple processes or threads to handle the different connections in a blocking way or use non-blocking sockets and select/poll/kqueue/... to handle everything within a single process. Once you've understood this you can deal with the HTTP part.

Comment: yes, you have hit the spot! I will try to look into select/poll/kqueue

Comment: You write: _as soon as I read it without writing, I get blocking_. 1. What is _it_? 2. Where do you _get blocking_?

Comment: in the event loop, in the above code, that is inside the while(1)